# How would I calibrate a tablet pc (pen input only) screen?

Tags: xorg, thinkpad, wacom

I have a 6-year old thinkpad X60 tablet. Legendary laptop, though its screen isn't very well calibrated by default in ubuntu. The screen appears as a 'Serial Wacom Tablet'. Is there a way to calibrate the screen on 13.04? I believe that the config file that used to have to be changed isn't in newer Xorg versions.

Answer (score 3):

There's an application in the Ubuntu Software Center named Calibrate Touchscreen (xinput_calibrator) that seems to be designed exactly for this job. I haven't ever used it so can't make any guarantees regarding whether or not it works, but the reviews are all positive, so hopefully this will solve your problem!

Comment: That doesn't change the xorg.conf or whatever to make the changes persistent. Nice program, though

Comment: From what I read on the application, it "generates an xorg.conf.d snippet", I presume you paste that into your xorg.conf to make it persistent.

Comment: I think they changed that, though. I have used that program before, and put the snippet in Xorg.conf, but I don't think that it did anything.

Comment: Tried putting it in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf (iirc that's the path) and since it's a quite minor calibration, I can't really tell if it worked or not.

Answer (score 1):

I had success using "Calibrate Touchscreen" (`xinput_calibrator`) the following way:

1. Determine the numerical device ID of the device you want to calibrate, from the output of:

   ```
   xinput list
   ```
2. If necessary, install the calibration tool:

   ```
   sudo apt install xinput-calibrator
   ```
3. Call the program with `xorg.conf.d` output mode:

   ```
   xinput_calibrator --device 14 --output-type xorg.conf.d
   ```
4. Note the MinX, MaxX, MinY, MaxY values from the output and supply them for the placeholders in the following command (14 is again the device ID):

   ```
   xinput set-prop 14 "Wacom Tablet Area" <MinX> <MinY> <MaxX> <MaxY>
   ```

   Alternatively, this command has the same effect:

   ```
   xsetwacom set Area <MinX> <MinY> <MaxX> <MaxY>
   ```
5. Execute the command and see if it calibrates your touchscreen right. (`xinput_calibrator` will only determine calibration values but not apply them at all.)
6. If the values are fine, put the command into your `~/.profile` or (to apply it system-wide) into a new shell script file in `/etc/profile.d/`.

**Details.** This rather complex process is because I encountered two problems:

- The xorg.conf.d snippets created by `xinput_calibrator` did not have any effect for me. I did not investigate, but the reason might be that it prints the wrong option names. They should rather be "TopX, TopY, BottomX, BottomY" [[source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1929783&p=11717691#post11717691)].
- Calling `xinput_calibrator` with `--output-type xinput` would result in "ERROR: XorgPrint Calibrator does not support the supplied --output-type" and not show the calibration result.